# Bash loop with multiple variables as input

Tags: bash

I'm trying to run a command using different variables as parameters. This is written as a bash script.

```
for i, j, k in $(seq 2 0.1 6), $(seq 2 0.25 5.5), $(seq 1 1 10)
do
    p.p_s_e r=100 a_t=S res=$i lam=$j s=$k sig=10 >> $k_lam_$j_res_$i.log
    p.p_s_e r=100 a_t=S res=$i lam=$j s=$k sig=20 >> $k_lam_$j_res_$i.log
    p.p_s_e r=100 a_t=S res=$i lam=$j s=$k sig=40 >> $k_lam_$j_res_$i.log
done
```

When I run this, the program does not take any of the values I am trying to give it. Sorry I can't be more clear about what I am trying to do. p.p_s_e is the program, the following X=y are variables, and I need to output to be written into a file. I think it's the way I am using for, do, done loops.

Comment: Do you want the assignments in parallel (the three first elements, the three second elements, etc), or do you want all possible combinations of `i`, `j`, and `k`? If the latter, you just need nested loops.

Comment: @Chris, try replacing the commands with echo "$i $j, $k" to isolate the problem. Look if what gets printed is expected.

Comment: ./test.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `j,'
./test.sh: line 1: `for i, j, k in $(seq 2 0.1 6), $(seq 2 0.25 5.5), $(seq 1 1 10)'

Comment: @chepner yes! All combinations of the three. I will have a look at nested loops. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need three loops. (Four, if you add a loop to iterate over the `sig` values as well.)

```
for i in $(seq 2 0.1 6); do
  for j in $(seq 2 0.25 5.5); do
    for k in $(seq 1 1 10); do
      for sig in 10 20 40; do
        p.p_s_e r=100 a_t=S res=$1 lam=$j s=$k sig=$sig
      done >> ${k}_lam_${j}_res_${i}.log
    done
  done
done
```

Comment: Thanks! Just spent the last hour watching videos on nested loops and came up with something very similar but much more convoluted!